# how to use the present perfect with "has"

Tags: present-perfect

I got this question:

*Ramy is ill. He became ill on Monday.*  **(How to use: Ramy has?)**

I think I could answer this question in a few ways like:

-> Ramy is ill. He has fallen ill on Monday

Or

Ramy is ill. He has become ill on Monday

is that a correct use of the present perfect?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think this is an odd question, and I'm not certain what they are looking for. But I think they want

*He has been ill since Monday*.

Your suggestions don't work because we don't usually use the perfect with a specific time reference ("on" or "at" as opposed to "since").

Also, we don't often use the perfect with "become", so when we do it usually has some special connotation, often that the change is significant. So if we say that somebody "has become ill", we usually don't mean that they have just caught a cold, but probably that they have a serious or long-term illness.

Comment: Thanks. It is interesting that "has become ill" implies a serious or long-term illness. The question indicates in a way that the person has been ill for few days. Now it makes sense.